# python-pip3 linux

Tags: kali-linux

Не устанавливается python-pip3.

Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
E: Не удалось найти пакет python3-pip[image: вот так выглядит в терминале]

Comment: У меня была такая же проблема на убунте, но питон3 и и пип3 я установил, однако убунта всё равно использует второй питон по умолчанию для всех своих основных программ, так что пришлось переходить на арч, чего и вам советую. На арче третий питон основной, а второй вообще нафиг не нужен.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:`sudo apt-get install python3-pip`
затем, когда будете устанавливать пакеты, пишите не `pip install <package>`, а `pip3 install <package>`